# jQuery - triggering two sequential click events more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox, click

When I first click on a box it enlarges and when I click it again it shrinks back to its original size. This applies for all the boxes. But when I click on a box that has gone through these two events it does not grow again. I want all my boxes to always be able to grow and shrink back to their original sizes, not just once. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lord_Breadwellington/9toseaw5/114/)

```
$(".item").on("click", function() {
        $(this).addClass("grow");
        $(".item").not(this).each(function() {
                $(this).addClass("collapse");
        })
        $(this).on("click", function() {
                $(this).removeClass("grow");
                $(".item").not(this).each(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("collapse");
                })
        })
})
```

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: You could do it with two lines only: http://jsfiddle.net/t9rsevqc/

Comment: I completely forgot about toggleclass. Thank you for easy fix!

Answer (score 2):

Why not checking for `.grow` class first? ↓
[**DEMO fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TOA_Anakin/fcxujrhp/7/)

```
$(".item").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("grow");
    $(".item").not(this).toggleClass("collapse");
})
```

Comment: No need to iterate, can use `$('.item').not(this).removeClass('collapse')` also.

Comment: Perfect, still new to jquery so I didn't think about doing a check. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write so long code. You can do this easily by using toggleClass() method. You even don't need collapse class to take box back to its normal position.

You can write your code as:

```
$(".item").on("click", function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("grow");
});
```

Comment: If I don't toggle the collapse class as well then the grown box may appear underneath another box, but I need the grown box to span the whole view port. Thank you for the suggestions though.